# eslint rule for curly spacing in function call

Tags: eslint

I have the following JS-code: In the 2nd line there's a brace, a space, a tab and finally the member `url`. I call `eslint --fix` and hope for something better than a mix of space and tab. In my `.eslintrc.json` file I set the directive `"object-curly-spacing" : [ "error", "always" ]`. I therefore hope eslint reduces the spaces between the brace and `url` to just one space which it does not.

Is there an `eslint` rule that corrects this mix of white spaces?

```js
            $.ajax(
            {   url : sURL,
                type : 'POST',
                data : {},
                success : function( data )
                {                   
                },
                async : false
            } );
```

Comment: can you please share the actual and expected code? also which version of ESlint are you using?

Comment: I installed latest eslint 4 alpha: `v4.0.0-alpha.2`. I setup a gist with the code sample: https://gist.github.com/bardware/ebba9c0fe3038eb15d9cb3a0c393f720  `eslint001.js` is the input, `eslint002.js` the output. The space after the opening brace remains. I expect either the space OR the TAB to be gone.